# Log requests made from Go server

Tags: go

In go how can I log request and response (error) for request made through http?

Currently I have this

```
package middleware

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)


type loggingTransport struct {
    transport http.RoundTripper
}


func (t *loggingTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // log the request
    dump, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error logging request: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Sending request:\n%s", string(dump))
    }

    // send the request
    res, err := t.transport.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // log the response
    dump, err = httputil.DumpResponse(res, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error logging response: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Received response:\n%s", string(dump))
     }
    if res.StatusCode >= 400 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("HTTP request failed with status code: %d", res.StatusCode)
    }
    return res, nil
}

func RequestMiddleware() http.RoundTripper {
    return &loggingTransport{http.DefaultTransport}
}
```

and then I am sending it like this in my main.go

```
client := &http.Client{
        Transport: middleware.RequestMiddleware(),
    }
    http.DefaultClient = client
```

but this isn't logging data for any of my request

```
func getUserInfo(accessToken string) (*domain.GetUserEmailResponse, error) {
    url := constants.GoogleUserInfoUrl + "?access_token=" + accessToken
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error sending HTTP request: %s", err.Error())
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    var user domain.GetUserEmailResponse
    if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&user); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error decoding JSON response: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return &user, nil
}
```

I am new to go, so not sure what I am doing wrong & how I can fix it?

Comment: When I [try to replicate this](https://go.dev/play/p/kKcm90UPJPI) it works (so the cause of your issue is not clear from your question; please try to share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Note that the playground will not be able to make the request (but does output the expected request data).